# ListViewItem MultiDataTrigger and AlternationIndex

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, listviewitem

So I tried to apply a different `Background` color to each `ListViewItem`:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=AlternationIndex}" Value="0"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=AlternationIndex}" Value="1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But it seems that this does not affect my `ListViewItem`s at all and all look the same.

**Update**

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="InnerBorder"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            CornerRadius="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>

        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use properties (or attached properties) of `ListBoxItem` in your conditions, you can simplify your style by using a [`MultiTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multitrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of a [`MultDataTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0"/>
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
   </MultiTrigger>
   <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1"/>
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
   </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Otherwise, use the attached property binding syntax with parentheses for [`AlternationIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which is an attached property of `ItemsControl`, fully qualify it: `(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)`.

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
   </MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
   </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-path-syntax) on binding syntax for attached properties:

> To bind to an attached property, place parentheses around the attached property. For example, to bind to the attached property `DockPanel.Dock`, the syntax is `Path=(DockPanel.Dock)`.

---

Update for your comments and update: You have to set the [`AlternationCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property on your `ListView` to the number of alternations explicitly - in you case two - otherwise the default value will be used, which is zero. If the alternation count is zero, the alternation index will also be zero for all items, see [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) in the documentation.

Comment: I used your code with MultiDataTrigger and all the ListViewItem colored with Blue

Comment: @RanPol Did you set the `AlternationCount` property on `ListView`, if so which value? E.g. `<ListView AlternationCount="2" ...>`.

Comment: No I did not use this AlternationCount

Comment: @RanPol You have to set it explicitly to the number of alternations, in you case two, otherwise the default value will be used, which is zero. In other words: If the alternation count is zero, the alternation index will also be zero for all items.